# Raspberry Pi 2 B "No wireless interfaces found" error

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wifi

i set up raspian os with recommended apps version on sdcard via noobs. it works on rpi successfully but without wireless connection.

- in rpi configuration window, set wifi country button is disabled.
- on the window top bar, when i click on the icon of wire connection
- (up and down arrows) , a popup fades "no wireless interfaces found"
  "ifconfig" command returns only lo and eth0. no wlan0.

system is up to date. i've already updated and upgraded the apt and the os. thanks.

Comment: The Pi2B does not have onboard wifi. Do you have an usb wifi adapter plugged in?

Comment: but there is a broadcom chip on it @Dirk (bcm2836rifbg)

Comment: googe `bcm2836rifbg`  and you get https://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi-2-the-new-quad-core-a7-pi2 - it's the CPU of the *older* Pi2 - the newer ones have bcm2873 like the pi 3 - but even then, do not have onboard wifi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RasPi 2B does not have an on-board WiFi chip, so what you see, that it isn't available, is all right. Look at [Raspberry Pi -  Generations of released models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Generations_of_released_models) that a Raspberry Pi Family 2 Model B does not provide Wireless. To use WiFi you need an additional USB/WiFi dongle.

Comment: but there is a broadcom chip on it (bcm2836rifbg)

Comment: @gks I don't have a RasPi 2B so I cannot say what this *bcm2836rifbg* do. You may google it. But it does not provide WiFi. I have updated the answer with additional info about the model.

Comment: thank you, i was driving crazy to fix problem.

Comment: @gks Glad to help you :-). If this answer your question, It would be nice if you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution (of course not to your satisfaction ;).